# Using Dailymotion API to retrieve Video IDs

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am trying to make a certain request work via the Dailymotion API, for work. Our client is a Dailymotion Partner who asked us to do 2 things from our application :

1. Generate a XML file to MRSS-upload their videos on Dailymotion (but we do not do the actual uploading, only the XML file creation)
2. Later, once they have uploaded their video, we have to get its Dailymotion ID (for logs necessities).

The thing is that this process has been developed circa 2012, and not fully tested. My job today is to make sure the process works now for good. In order to get the ID, we have been using this request:

https://api.dailymotion.com/video/PARTNER_NAME:GUID?fields=id

but I can't find any mention of "partner" and "guid" in the Dailymotion Documentation today. All I know is that we use the name of the channel as PARTNER_NAME and the guid we put in the XML file as GUID.

The thing I don't understand is that:

- sometimes, the request does succeed and I get the ID,
- most of the time, I get alternatively "400" and "403" errors from the API.

First, I tried to set the attribute "private" in the XML file to 'false', and it helped get the ID of some videos imported as public, but it does not do the trick for all videos.

Could someone show some light on this matter?